# TypeORM Querybuilder get nested INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have a `TripEntity` that references a `Vehicle` in column `vehicle_id`. The `VehicleEntity` itself references the `VehicleDetailsEntity` in column `vehicle_details_id`.

TripEntity

| id | vehicle_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 |

VehicleEntity

| id | vehicle_details_id |
| --- | --- |
| 99 | 100 |

VehicleDetailsEntity

| id | registration_plate |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | DOGETOMOON |

How can I use `QueryBuilder` to get all three: TripEntity, VehicleEntity and VehicleDetails?

```
    const trip = await db
      .createQueryBuilder(TripEntity, "trip")
      .innerJoinAndSelect("trip.vehicle_id", "vehicle")
      /* This does not work...
      .innerJoinAndSelect("vehicle. vehicle_details_id", "details")
     */
      .where("trip.created_at >= :after",{ after })
      .getMany();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think defining the join condition explicitly would solve the problem.
Please check the following query -

```
async findVehicleDetails(request): Promise<any>{
    return await getRepository(TripEntity).
    .createQueryBuilder("tripEntity")
    .innerJoinAndSelect("VehicleEntity","vehicleEntity","vehicleEntity.id = tripEntity.vehicle_id")
    .innerJoinAndSelect("VehicleDetailsEntity","vehicleDetailsEntity","vehicleDetailsEntity.id = vehicleEntity.vehicle_details_id")
    .where("tripEntity.created_at >= :after",{ after })
    .getMany()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are joining multiple entities, you can try `innerJoinAndMapOne` instead.

```js
const trips = (await db
  .createQueryBuilder(TripEntity, "trip")
  .innerJoinAndMapOne(
    "trip.vehicle",
    VehicleEntity,
    "vehicle",
    "trip.vehicle_id = vehicle.id"
  )
  .innerJoinAndMapOne(
    "trip.vehicleDetails",
    VehicleDetailsEntity,
    "vehicle_details",
    "vehicle.vehicle_details_id = vehicle_details.id"
  )
  .where("trip.created_at >= :after", { after })
  .getMany()) as (TripEntity & {
    vehicle: VehicleEntity;
    vehicleDetails: VehicleDetailsEntity;
  })[];
```